Howto autoscroll when appendText to etherpad component
I use etherpad javascript editor. https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite.
I use appendText to append new text at the end. When component is full of text, newly appended text is not visible until I manually scroll it down.
Is there way to scroll down automatically, so that I have not to manually scroll it down by mouse?
Here is gif
Manually scroll down
I tried to change scrollWhenFocusLineIsOutOfViewport.percentage.editionAboveViewport and scrollWhenFocusLineIsOutOfViewport.percentage.editionBellowViewport settings in setting.json file but it did not work.

you can do it by simply appending a new text something like this:
// scroll to the bottom of the Etherpad editor
function scrollToBottom() {
  var editor = document.querySelector(".pad-content"); // Add Selector Here
  editor.scrollTop = editor.scrollHeight;
}

// append text and scroll to bottom
function appendTextAndScroll(text) {
  // Append text to the Etherpad editor
  padeditor.ace.callWithAce((ace) => {
    ace.ace_replaceRange([], text);
  });

  // Scroll to the bottom after appending text
  scrollToBottom();
}

// usage
appendTextAndScroll("This is the new text to append.");

